# Cors блокировка fetch запроса с React js на PHP

Tags: php, reactjs, сервер, fetch, cors

Если вкратце, у меня есть 2 приложения, 1-е на реакте, фронт, которое фетчит запросы на второе, которое уже написано на php и нужно только для того, чтобы работать с бд и выдавать ответ назад, на стадии разработки я не особо думал о CORS блокировках и прочими межсерверными проблемами, но когда я выложил бэк php и фронт реакта, на фронте естественно поменял ссылку с локалки на новый хост, на который выложил бэк, но у меня появилась проблема с блокировкой CORS, начав гуглить я понял, что это необходимо, но не понимаю, как мне добавить на бэке мой фронт в исключения блокировки, я нагуглил про `headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://test-host.ru');` 
Но когда я закидываю эту строку в самое начало файла, у меня он перестаёт открываться, его видимо блокирует хостинг (хост бэка на php), я не уверен, но возможно это из-за Headers.append, видимо сам хост отслеживает такие мувы и не запускает их, может есть что-то другое? Мне в целом подойдёт даже отключение CORS, на этих сайтах нет никакой информации.
На фронте выдаёт такую ошибку: (скрин) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я убрал .append  и вроде ошибка пропала, но данные не передались, сейчас буду пробовать передать данные.

Comment: потому что закидывать надо не `headers.append` а `header("Name: Value")`. Если вы потрудитесь прочитать. что там в ответ отдается по вашему запросу то увидите всякие ошибки относительно неизвестных констант `headers` и ее конкатенации неизвестной функцией append, что  и приведет к фатальной ошибке

Comment: Это был скрин одной из проб, я уже всё поправил и сделал ровно так, как написано у вас, о чём и сообщил